# How to use subdomain in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to put my cakephp 3.8 in a subdomain: demo.myweb.com

and i have this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'myweb.clients' doesn't exist
```

Is the same app in my original domain: `www.myweb.com`

I tried this on my routes.php:

```
Router::scope('/', ['prefix' => 'demo'], function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
```

when i put in a subdomain thrown me that error.
Whats things i have to change to work fine in a subdomain?

Comment: This is a SQL error indicating that it can't find a particular table. When you moved it, did you change the database configuration, or forget to move a `.env` file or some such?

Comment: The prefix router is not the subdomain. The prefix router provides a namespace to group controllers. CakePHP isn't really aware of your domain (which is fine). Meaning that you can rename your domain or vhost without any consequences (for your Cake app).

Comment: @GregSchmidt everything is the same as the original domain page,